# Using stdin with VS studio and never return any data - Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

import 'dart:io';void main() {  print("somethinh");String x = stdin.readLineSync()!; print('maher $x');
}

Comment: You have not described a problem or asked any sort of specific question. Questions that do not include any content other than code in the body are not acceptable here.  Please read [ask] and [mre], and then come back and [edit] your post. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('Enter your name');
  String no1 = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print('name is $no1');

Answer (score 0):

Dart scripts are run in the "Debug Console" by default, where the input box works as a REPL. If you need to read input from the user, you need to change it to run in a terminal.

You can do this by creating a `launch.json` file and adding `"console": "terminal",` as described here:

https://dartcode.org/docs/running-in-terminal/

Or you can add the [`"dart.cliConsole": "terminal"`](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartcliconsole) setting in your VS Code Workspace Settings for this project.